# What is the parent class of SoftwareSerial and Serial

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, arduino-uno

I wanted to create a function to pass a serial port by reference for reading content. and I use SoftwareSerial and Serial in combination, meaning I want to pass both Objects to the function I want to create. What class do they both inherit from? what class should I declare my source object?

```
void getResponse(Serial &source){
    ...
}
```

Comment: The arduino language is based on C++, not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the common base classes for Arduino Serial and SoftwareSerial are Stream and Print

[image]