# Reading line by line in Arduino IDE

Tags: file, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to read txt file (has numeric values) line by line.
I used SPIFFS and I used this function

```
void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
   Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\r\n", path);

   File file = fs.open(path);
   if(!file || file.isDirectory()){
       Serial.println("− failed to open file for reading");
       return;
   }
   
   int count = 0;
   Serial.println(" read from file:");

   while(file.available()){
    if (count < 100)  
      Serial.write(file.read());  
   } 
}
```

What is the alternative function for "file.read()" something like "readline" because I need to read the file from first line to 100 and from 101 to 200 and so on .

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadbytesuntil/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `readStringUntil`. Although it's not the most efficient way, i'll show you how it's done.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <SPIFFS.h>

std::vector<double> readLine(String path, uint16_t from, uint16_t to) {
  std::vector<double> list;
  if(from > to) return list;
  File file = SPIFFS.open(path.c_str());
  if(!file) return list;
  uint16_t counter = 0;
  while(file.available() && counter <= to) {
    counter++;
    if(counter < from) {
      file.readStringUntil('\n');
    } else {
      String data = file.readStringUntil('\n');
      list.push_back(data.toDouble());
    }
  }
  return list;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPIFFS.begin(true);
  
  std::vector<double> numbers = readLine("file.txt", 0, 100);
  Serial.println("Data from 0 to 100:");
  uint16_t counter = 0;
  for (auto& n : numbers) {
    counter++;
    Serial.print(String(n) + "\t");
    if(counter % 10 == 0) {
      Serial.println();
    }
  }

  numbers = readLine("file.txt", 101, 200);
  Serial.println("\nData from 101 to 200:");
  counter = 0;
  for (auto& n : numbers) {
    counter++;
    Serial.print(String(n) + "\t");
    if(counter % 10 == 0) {
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Supposed you have 1050 values and you want to parse it for each 100 values.

```cpp
int i = 0;
while(i < 1050) {
  int start = i + 1;
  int end = (i + 100) > 1050 ? 1050 : i + 100;
  std::vector<double> numbers = readLine("file.txt", start, end);
  
  Serial.println("Data from " + String(start) + " to " + String(end) + ":");
  uint16_t counter = 0;
  for (auto& n : numbers) {
    counter++;
    Serial.print(String(n) + "\t");
    if(counter % 10 == 0) {
      Serial.println();
    }
  }

  i += 100;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if my file contain on 1050 value 
and I need in each time read 100, 100,100,... , until the end of file 
and the last 50 values are not read because they are less than 100 how can do that?

Comment: Hi @kayla , just read the data as of the following:
`readLine("file.txt", 1001, 1050);`

Comment: how can repeat this code to include all file size?
std::vector<double> numbers = readLine("file.txt", 0, 100);
  Serial.println("Data from 0 to 100:");
  uint16_t counter = 0;
  for (auto& n : numbers) {
    counter++;
    Serial.print(String(n) + "\t");
    if(counter % 10 == 0) {
      Serial.println();
    }
  }

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but why the output just printing Data from 1 to 100: Data from 101 to 200: Data from 201 to 300: Data from 301 to 400: Where this part does not work 
for (auto& n : numbers) { 
    counter++;
    Serial.print(String(n) + "\t");
    if(counter % 10 == 0) {
      Serial.println();
    }
  }

Comment: If it's not printing, then the vector is empty. If the vector is empty, then the data in SPIFFS are also empty.

Comment: No,  the data in SPIFFS are not empty!

Comment: It's necessarily the SPIFFS it self doesn't contains data. What i mean is that the file you are lookong for may be empty. You should check if the file is not empty

Answer (score 1):

To read lines from Serial, network Client, from File or other object implementing the Arduino [Stream class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263300/what-is-the-parent-class-of-softwareserial-and-serial/65263590#65263590) you can use function [readBytesUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadbytesuntil/).

```
uint8_t lineBuffer[64];
while (file.available()) {
  int length = file.readBytesUntil('\n', lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer) - 1);
  if (length > 0 && lineBuffer[length - 1] == '\r') {
    length--; // to remove \r if it is there
  }
  lineBuffer[length] = 0; // terminate the string
  Serial.println(lineBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The File is a [Stream](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/) and has all of the methods that a Stream does, including [readBytesUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadbytesuntil/) and [readStringUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadstringuntil/).

Comment: and how to use it to read a file line by line?